# PrintWriter Class. What does Create a new PrintWriter, without automatic line flushing, from an existing OutputStream mean?

Tags: java

`PrintWriter(OutputStream out)` this method does not automatic line flushing.

```
PrintWriter(OutputStream out, boolean autoFlush)
```

This method does automatic line flushing.

My question is what is line flushing?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        int myInt = 2;



        PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(System.out);

        outFile.println();
        outFile.println(myInt);

    }
}
```

the output of the program is nothing WHy?

If i add in True in the PrintWriter construtor, it prints out 2 in the console.

Ex:

```
PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(System.out, true);
```

So what does line flushing mean? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behaviour.  Setting auto flush or calling `flush` on a stream/writer forces any buffers to be written.

See javadoc of [OutputStream.flush](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#flush%28%29) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

The `autoFlush` flag is for only `println()`, `printf()` and `format()` method of `PrintWriter()`. If you don't set this flag (or use the constructor without the boolean flag), you will have to explicitly call `flush()` method on `PrintWriter` object after calling the above-mentioned methods.

**References**:

- [`PrintWriter(Writer writer, boolean autoFlush)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter%28java.io.Writer,%20boolean%29)